# Is strong unimodality preserved under Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

A unimodal distribution $F$ is said to be strongly unimodal if its convolution with any unimodal distribution is itself unimodal. Is the strong unimodality property preserved by the Fourier transform?

Comment: Is this about probability distributions?

Comment: Yes, essentially.